# How to "computeIfAbsent" / "getOrElseUpdate" a Map in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, dictionary

Assuming that

- `m` is a `Map<number, V>` for some type `V`
- `k` is a `number`,

how do I write down an expression that

- either gets an already existing `V` for the key `k`, or
- creates a new `v: V`, puts it into the map for the key `k`, and evaluates to `v`?

For example, `SOME_EXPR(m, k, [])` should either return `m.get(k)` if it already exists, or put the `[]` into `m.set(k, [])` and return the `[]`.

---

**Concrete example**

Suppose that I want to incrementally build a `Map<number, number[]>`.
I want to assign values `100` and `200` to the key `48`, and value `300` to `52`.
I want to create new empty arrays on demand whenever needed.
For this, I need something like an `SOME_EXPR(map, key, value)` such that

```
var m = new Map(); // Map<number, number[]>
SOME_EXPR(m, 48, []).push(100)
SOME_EXPR(m, 48, []).push(200)
SOME_EXPR(m, 52, []).push(300)
```

results in a map

```
{ 48 -> [100, 200]; 52 -> [300] }
```

What should one write instead of `SOME_EXPR`?

---

**What I've tried**

I could, of course, create a helper method:

```
function getOrElseUpdate(m, k, defaultValue) {
  if (!m.has(k)) {
    m.set(k, defaultValue);
  }
  return m.get(k);
}
```

and then use `SOME_EXPR(m, k, []) := getOrElseUpdate(m, k, [])`. But not only does it have to compute the hash code thrice, it's also just heavyweight and annoying (and possibly not obvious to the maintainer of the code, who has to click on it to see the definition in yet another file etc.).

I could try to inline this somehow:

```
SOME_EXPR(m,k,v) := ((k) => (m.get(k) || ((v) => (m.set(k, v), v))(v)))(k)
```

so that the above example would become

```
var m = new Map();
((k) => (m.get(k) || ((v) => (m.set(k, v), v))([])))(42).push(100);
((k) => (m.get(k) || ((v) => (m.set(k, v), v))([])))(42).push(200);
((k) => (m.get(k) || ((v) => (m.set(k, v), v))([])))(58).push(300);
```

which works, but is just bizarre.

I've also tried looking around for related answers, but this search turned out frustratingly unfruitful.

Is there any idiomatic way to achieve that? (preferably also in a way that's nicely typeable in TS)

---

**Analogous methods from some other languages**

*(optional; skip this if you're not into JVM)*

In Scala, it would look like somewhat like this:

```scala
val m = HashMap.empty[Int, ListBuffer[Int]]
m.getOrElseUpdate(48, ListBuffer.empty) += 100
m.getOrElseUpdate(48, ListBuffer.empty) += 200
m.getOrElseUpdate(52, ListBuffer.empty) += 300

// m is now:
//
// HashMap(
//   48 -> ListBuffer(100, 200), 
//   52 -> ListBuffer(300)
// )
```

In Java, very similarly:

```java
HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>> m = new HashMap<>();
m.computeIfAbsent(42, k -> new LinkedList<>()).add(100);
m.computeIfAbsent(42, k -> new LinkedList<>()).add(200);
m.computeIfAbsent(58, k -> new LinkedList<>()).add(300);

// m = {58=[300], 42=[100, 200]}
```

Comment: Have you thought of adding a method to the class prototype? `Map.prototype.computeIfAbsent = function(key, computer) {...}`.

Comment: This looks promising: [emplace](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-upsert#normalization-of-values-during-insertion), but it's still only a proposal.

Comment: @smac89 As I'm trying to use it inside of TypeScript project, I'm a bit suspicious about modifying the `prototype`s, because I'm not sure where to even get the types of keys and values to begin with. Also, I'm not sure whether it would mess up code navigation in some IDEs to which I currently have no access. So, yes, it's interesting, but I'd prefer something more lightweight.

Comment: `emplace` does look promising, but the proposed API is too complex; I see no reason why emplace should update the value, if the goal is to insert if the key does not exist. Also the name is too similar to the C++ equivalent, where the name _emplace_ is used to indicate that the key and value are being constructed _in place_, not necessarily anything to do with "_updating if not existing_"

Comment: Polyfills are quite common in JS/TS. The only difference with TS is that you also have to include a declaration file if your polyfill adds new functionality. It's up to you though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried code golfing your idiomatic example down a bit:

```
((k, d) => m.get(k) ?? (m.set(k, d), d))(48, []).push(100);
```

I actually think calling a function something like `getOrElseUpdate` can help serve as documentation. If the maintainer stumbles across it, it's possible s/he knows Scala and will know what it should do.

Comment: Ah, yes, why on Earth did I start with two nested closures in the first place *facepalm*.  Nice one, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I tried a bunch of options, but if you're simply looking for readability I personally think this is the best option, I could be wrong and would like to see something more elegant;

```
var m = new Map();

function SOME_EXPR(m, k, v) {
  return m.get(k) || (m.set(k, v) && v);
}

function add(m, k, v) {
  SOME_EXPR(m, k, []).push(v)
}

add(m, 48, 100)
add(m, 48, 200)
add(m, 52, 300)

console.log(m);
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably not much improvement and the drawback of spread operator, but what do you think of this?

```
function addValue(m, k, v) {
    m.set(k, [...(m.get(k) || []), v]);
}

var map = new Map();
addValue(map, 48, 100);
addValue(map, 48, 200);
addValue(map, 52, 300);

console.log(map);
```

Comment: I find it quite surprising and inspiring, +1 for creativity. The method should probably be named something like `addValue` though, it's doing something slightly different than the `computeIfAbsent` from the Java example above.

Comment: It can also be adapted such that a function accepts an array of values. Then the second spread operator could be removed, and the function can be called only once per key. Thanks!

Comment: What's the point of `...[v]`?

Comment: @caTS good point - removed